# Change CSS with Jquery and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to change the size of image via JS function.
I have table with Images, and I want that if the user click on Image her size will change to 400,400 , **and** all the other image will set to the default 100,100.
I make OnClick event for every image in the table that operate the next function:

```
function ChangeSize(it) {
    $('td img not(it)' ).css({"width":"100","height":"100"});
    if (it.width == 100)
    {
        it.width = 400;
        it.height=400;
    }
    else
    {
        it.width = 100;
        it.height=100;
    }
}
```

I know that my Jquery not work. but How Can I do that?

thank you!

Comment: What is the value of `it`?

Comment: this is the event of every image in the table: onclick="ChangeSize(this)"

Comment: `$("td img").click(function(){ $("td img").css({"width":"100",
        "height":"100"}); $(this).css({"width":"400",
        "height":"400"}); });`

Comment: Hi thanks that's work, but I want that double click on the same image , will change it back to the defualt size. that's why I make the condition in my func (it.width==100) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much better way to achieve this is to set the 100x100 size as default size and to apply a class on the clicked one:

```
td img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
img.selected {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

function ChangeSize(it) {
  $('td img').removeClass('selected');
  $(it).addClass('selected');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If `it` is an DOMElement:

`$('td img not(it)')` is an invalid selector, use `$('td img').not(it)`

Answer (score 0):

rather, use:

```
    function ChangeSize(it) {
    $('td img').not(it).css({"width":"100px",
        "height":"100px"});
    if (parseInt(it.width) == 100)
    {it.width = 400+'px';
    it.height=400+'px';}
    else
    {it.width = 100+'px';
    it.height=100+'px';}
    }
```

I hope this fixes the bug

Comment: it's supposed to be `:not()`

Comment: actually, its supposed to be  $('td img').not(it)

Comment: well, you can either use `:not()` as selector or `.not()` as method. In the case, where you have a Dom-Element rathern than a selector string, you of course need the latter one. I just wanted to point out, that the  syntax for the selector was faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
function ChangeSize(it) {
    $('td img').css({"width":"100", "height":"100"});
    $(it).css({"width":"400", "height":"400"});
}
```